# How do I read and return data from firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to read data from firebase db and return values to another method.To do that I added interface and use it as a callback function and tried to wait until data filled. But it still give the null pointer exception.

```
private interface FirebaseCallback {
    void onCallBack(Card card);
}


// method to read travel Cards
public void readCard(final FirebaseCallback fb) {

    cardNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextCardNo);

    ValueEventListener cardListner = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                travelCard = dataSnapshot.getValue(Card.class);
                fb.onCallBack(travelCard);

            }

            else displayMessage(inValidTravelCard);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("ERROR : ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };

    String cn = cardNo.getText().toString();
    Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Card").orderByChild("cardNumber").equalTo(cn).limitToFirst(1);
    q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(cardListner);

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_reader);

                  System.out.println("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff    " +  " BEFORE>..........................");

            readCard(new FirebaseCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCallBack(Card card) {
                    Log.d("card = ",card.getAccountId());
                }
            });

            System.out.println("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff    " +  " After>..........................");
        }
    });

}
```

Here's the ERROR :

[image]

Here's the database

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse the stack trace you get the error message you get is `println needs a message`, triggered from `Log.d`. In the code you shared, there are two statements that could trigger that message:

```
Log.d("ERROR : ", databaseError.getMessage());
```

And

```
Log.d("card = ",card.getAccountId());
```

It seems quite unlikely that `databaseError.getMessage()` returns nothing, so it's more likely that `card.getAccountId()` returns nothing or `null`. A simple solution is to check for that:

```
Log.d("card = ", card.getAccountId() != null ? card.getAccountId() : "No account ID found on card");
```

Null pointer exceptions are extremely common, and knowing how to troubleshoot them is a skill that will serve you well. I recommend studying:  [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).